# Shuffle list contents in CMake

Tags: cmake

this question is slightly less ordinary because usually CMake users want to sort list into some reproducible order.

In my case, I would like to have the list contents (here: SOURCES of a CMake target) in a random order (shuffled). This is because I am working on contributed code of mediocre quality, so sometimes there are multiple bugs of different kinds involved, including configuration errors, and restarting the build from scratch all the time and wait until the errors comes after ~90% of the build process is a huge time waster.

So I looked around on how to do it and no simple implementation seems to exist. I could dump my list to a file and run `shuf` utility on it, but this is maybe not optimal. Because there is no "INPUT_VARIABLE" flag for execute_process, and dumping variables to file just to get that via STDIN raises some eyebrows. In CMake itself, I could not find a "shuffle" module. There is only `string(RANDOM ...)` which could be abused in a macro (i.e. make it generate numbers and use the numbers to remove items from a list). But I really doubt that this would perform well.

Does anyone have a better idea on how to implement such permutation?

Comment: Side note: since reproducible builds are usually a way to avoid issues, I'm not sure to understand how doing the exact opposite is going to prevent them =)

Comment: `use the numbers to remove items from a list` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: How does shuffling the files make it faster to get to re-attempting to compile translation units that previously failed? Shouldn't most buildsystems' mechanisms to skip unnecessary recompilation already be helpful for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not have a better idea. This was fun:

```
function(log10_int_up ret x)
  set(res 1)
  while(x GREATER_EQUAL 10)
    math(EXPR x "${x} / 10")
    math(EXPR res "${res} + 1")
  endwhile()
  set("${ret}" "${res}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

function(get_random ret max)
  if(max LESS_EQUAL 0)
    message(FATAL_ERROR)
  endif()
  log10_int_up(len "${max}")
  string(RANDOM LENGTH "${len}" ALPHABET 0123456789 res)
  while(res GREATER_EQUAL max)
    string(RANDOM LENGTH "${len}" ALPHABET 0123456789 res)
  endwhile()
  math(EXPR res "${res}")
  set("${ret}" "${res}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

function(list_shuffle ret inputlist)
  list(LENGTH inputlist inputlen)
  set(res)
  foreach(len RANGE "${inputlen}" 1 -1)
    get_random(idx "${len}")
    list(GET inputlist "${idx}" elem)
    list(APPEND res "${elem}")
    list(REMOVE_AT inputlist "${idx}")
  endforeach()
  set("${ret}" "${res}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()    

set(mylist
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e
  f
)
list_shuffle(newlist "${mylist}")
message(STATUS "${mylist}")
message(STATUS "${newlist}")
```

Comment: [CMake docs for `foreach(RANGE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/foreach.html): *The three arguments <start> <stop> <step> must all be **nonnegative** integers, and <stop> must not be smaller than <start>; otherwise you enter the danger zone of undocumented behavior that may change in future releases*.

Comment: Yes that what says, would be nice to add why are you commenting next time ;) . Do you point is -1 is unspecified. Looks simple to fix with some additional set(math . If you feel like it, feel free to edit the answrr to fix it .